# PHP cURL randomly timeouts with 100% of body received

Tags: go, nginx, curl

We have an app with ~50 front servers with PHP code that make total 15-25k HTTP RPS to GO API servers via nginx with 100ms timeout using `guzzle` library. From time to time (randomly, few times in a day) we see that 500-10k RPS are failed with curl timeout error in PHP front servers logs. All exceptions inside logs look like:

`cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 100 milliseconds with 143 out of 143 bytes received`.

The most interesting part is that it's always `100% out of 100%` bytes received, there are never `100 of 102` or `0 of 70`. So the PHP receives complete body (we're sure about that because when we replay these requests via CLI curl, its size always equals to failed response body size).

When we start to trace these timed out requests inside nginx-access logs we see, that each of that requests is successfully proceeded by upstream services (Go API) in 1ms (average) and returned by nginx without any delay. Nginx access logs:

`GET [path] HTTP/1.1" 200 228 "-" [...] request_time: 0.001 upstream_addr: [addr] upstream_response_time: 0.001 upstream_status: 200`

- nginx is tunned for max clients (millions of connections) as i talked to our dev-ops guys;
- 99-th percentile of response time in Go service < 1ms;

What can be the problem of 100ms timeout and where to dig to solve it?

**UPD:**

NGINX configuration related to client connections:

```
worker_processes        32;
worker_rlimit_nofile    65535;

events {
    worker_connections      32767;
    accept_mutex on;
}

upstream [service] {
    server [main] max_fails=0;
    server [...] backup max_fails=0;
    keepalive 16;
}

location ^~ /[path]/ {
    proxy_pass http://[service]/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;

    keepalive_timeout 30;
    keepalive_requests 500;

    reset_timedout_connection on;

    proxy_set_header Connection "";
}
```

GO version 1.13. `net/http` is used to serve clients. The service has no external dependencies (databases, cache, etc.), it's just calculating hash for incoming request based on input data.

PHP version 7.2.0 uses `guzzlehttp/guzzle@5.3.4` HTTP client

Comment: Why is Nginx involved?

Comment: @Adrian because it's used as proxy + load balancer from public clients to internal go services. Go service is running on 3 instances.

Comment: Given how much is going on, there's a bunch of potential points of failure, from the Go code, to the Nginx configuration, to the PHP code, to whatever is serving PHP (php-fpm in nginx?). It's impossible to say without seeing any of it.

Answer (score -2):

On your Load balancer you should force close connection when request is finish

```
backend nodes
  ...
  option forceclose
  ...
```

By doing this the load balancer will close the connection when it see the response transfered

https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#option%20forceclose

Comment: Why?  This answer doesn't give any justification as to why this is causing the problem.

Comment: We don’t have haproxy as balancer, only nginx